# Происхождение слова "тарелка"?

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "тарелка"?

Answer (score 4):

Найдено два варианта:

- Происходит от ср.-в.-нем. talier «тарелка» (ср. баварск. taller — то же). Восходит к итал. tagliere от tagliare «резать», далее из лат. taliāre. Из итал. также заимств. нов.-греч. ταλέρι. Др.-русск. тарѣль (откуда русск. тарелка) заимств., вероятно, через польск. talerz, чешск. talíř «тарелка». Ср.: укр. талíр, тарíль, тарíлка, белор. тале́рка.
- Слово ТАРЕЛКА образовалось от латинского ТАЛЬЯРЭ – «резать». Изначально ТАРЕЛКА – «отрезанный кусок доски» (для пищи). ТАРЕЛКА – ТАЛЬЯРЭ = «резать».

Comment: А в чём отличие между двумя версиями? И там, и там от латинского, но в первой ещё и путь расписан.

Comment: 1) неужели [так ма...] всего два?

2) можно посмотреть ссылки, если это в Интернете?

Comment: >А в чём отличие между двумя версиями?  
  
См. в моем ответе. С точки зрения этимологии - это разные версии.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь еще явление метатезы (произошла перестановка Л и Р, видимо, для удобства произношения)

Comment: +1
Только не "для", а "как". Вряд ли метатеза может быть сознательной. И вообще - и в конкретном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то раньше считалось, что "таЛеРка" произведено напрямую от германского "талера", который, кстати, предок "доллара". Хотя, может, и через польский...
Касательно латинского первоисточника - да, но это только "к сведению". Принято считать, что этимология заимствованного слова ограничивается языком, откуда заимствовано напрямую. Иначе даже с самым простым словом можно дойти до такой древности, что отсюда не видно.  
Этот подход означает, в частности, что два (и даже три) представленных варианта этимологии - принципиально разные, хотя все они и содержат указание на латинский праисточник.

Comment: Я тоже всегда так думал (про талер). Но в Интернете не нашёл подтверждений (а только опровержения).

Comment: Ну в интернете много чего можно найти. Я-то, собственно, сказал про "талер" более для "опровержения" латинской версии.   
А все остальное - обсуждаемо. Что там за опровержения, ссылочка есть?

Comment: Есть мнение у конкурентов: http://otvet.mail.ru/question/7329163 (находится в Яндексе по словам "этимология тарелка").

Comment: да какие они конкуренты...
Все бы хорошо, но сами немцы возводят свою тарелку к латинскому talea.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teller

Тогда получается, что история с ефимикой ("Иогансталлер") опровергает только значение "таллер", от которого произошло русское тарелка, но никак не не сам факт родственности немецкого das Teller и русской тарелки.  
Нехай так. Я не против. Главное, что в основе все-таки "тарелка" немецкая и последующая метатеза.

Answer (score -1):

От белорусского "талерка". Блюдо, на которое в костёле (церкви) клали пожертвования - талеры - монеты.